# Stamp’ed item in Masonry being completely ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, masonry

**SOLVED: issue was the masonry-rails gem; it used an older fork of masonry that did not have the stamp option. Adding the masonry CDN to the project has resolved the issue.**

I’ve been trying to get the ‘stamp’ functionality in masonry working in a Rails project. What I want is for the masonry items to fit themselves into the empty space around my 'stamp'ed object, and for my stamped object to be locked to the upper right corner of the parent element. However, the stamped element appears to be excluded from any Masonry positioning altogether, and instead masonry tiles everything in the div as if the stamp doesn’t exist in the layout. I can’t get the functionality to work the way I intend at all.

Nothing happens when I press the button in desandro's codepen example: https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/wKpjs, so I don't really know if I have some kind of browser/OS/library problem or if I'm just stamping wrong.

This is the current state of the page:
[images tiled underneath stamped element, instead of tiled around it](https://vgy.me/Zum95l.jpg)

Layout in HAML:

```
#signupGal.centered
  - if @displayPix.present?
    - @displayPix.each_with_index do |pic,i|
        = link_to pic do 
            .picTile{:id => "tile#{i}"}
                :javascript
                    $('#tile#{i}').css({
                        "background-image":'url(' + "#{pic.image.url(:medium)}" + ')',
                        "background-position":"center",
                        "background-size":"cover"
                    });

  .signupForm.bg.tc
```

CSS:

```
.bg {
    background-color: rgb(63,168,161);
}

.tc {
    color: white;
}

.signupForm {
    width: 752px;
    height: 558px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 1%;
    top: 10px;
    width: 80%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 3px solid white;
    padding: 1em;
}

#signupGal {
    max-width: 1200px;
    position: relative;
    .picTile {
      width: 160px;
      height: 120px;
      float: left;
      margin-bottom: 3px;
      margin-right: 3px;
    }
}

/* clearfix */
#signupGal:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

And in a coffeescript file:

```
$ ->
    $('#signupGal').imagesLoaded ->
        $gallery = $('#signupGal')
        $gallery.masonry
            isAnimated: true
            isFitWidth: true
            itemSelector: '.picTile'
            stamp: '.signupForm'
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because I was using the masonry-rails gem, whose fork of masonry is 3.x and whose stamp functionality and interface was not identical to the current documentation. There were no errors or warnings, the 'stamp' option literally just had no effect. Once I removed the gem and added the current masonry CDN, the above code started to display expected behavior.

This issue was compounded by jsfiddle and codepen failing silently (until the console was opened) because of mixed content for a lot of code examples.